# Как обучить нейросеть SSD на собственном наборе данных?

Tags: python, neuralbase

Хочу обучить нейронную сеть Single Shot Detector для распознавания людей в режиме реального времени на наборе данных [CEPDOF](https://vip.bu.edu/projects/vsns/cossy/datasets/cepdof/) с использованием языка Python.
Как правильно загрузить и подготовить данные для тренировки модели?

Comment: А в описании самой нейросети не описан процесс подготовки данных?

Comment: Я пробовала несколько вариантов ([link](https://github.com/sunshiding/ssd-pytorch-custom), [link](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd)), но там данные в формате .xml, .txt помимо самих изображений, а в CEPDOF только наборы изображений и аннотации .json.